# Why does pylint assess itself?

Tags: python-2.7, pylint, pep8

I'm trying to run pylint against my flask application.
I generated the default pylint configuration file.

When I run this command:

```
(newedgeuiv) Callams-MacBook-Pro:api callam$ pylint pylint --load-plugins pylint_flask --confidence="HIGH" api/
```

Pylint starts out by assessing itself.. as seen here:

```
************* Module pylint

C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)

************* Module pylint.__main__

C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)

************* Module pylint.config

C: 55, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)

C: 68, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)

C:263, 0: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)

C:311, 0: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)

C:615,12: Invalid argument name "p" (invalid-name)

C:615,12: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)

C:633,68: Invalid variable name "fp" (invalid-name)

************* Module pylint.epylint

C:163, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)

************* Module pylint.lint

C:196, 4: Missing class docstring (missing-docstring)

C:1086,16: Invalid variable name "cb" (invalid-name)

C:1354, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)

************* Module pylint.testutils
C: 42, 0: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)
```

How can I ensure pylint only checks the code I've written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked it to. There is an extraneous **pylint** in your command, you have **pylint pylint  api/**